# Можно ли разделить файл на несколько файлов и дать им названия?

Tags: php

Имеется огромный XML файл со следующей структурой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Catalog>
<Category>
<Name>Cat 1</Name>
<Site>...</Site>
<Site>...</Site>
<Site>...</Site>
</Category>
<Category>
<Name>Cat 2</Name>
<Site>...</Site>
<Site>...</Site>
<Site>...</Site>
</Category>
<Category>
<Name>Cat 3</Name>
<Site>...</Site>
<Site>...</Site>
<Site>...</Site>
</Category>
</Catalog>
```

Можно ли его разделить с помощью PHP на несколько файлов так, чтобы в каждом файле сохранялась одна категория?

Например так:

**cat_1.php**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Catalog>
<Category>
<Name>Cat 1</Name>
<Site>...</Site>
<Site>...</Site>
<Site>...</Site>
</Category>
</Catalog>
```

**cat_2.php**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Catalog>
<Category>
<Name>Cat 2</Name>
<Site>...</Site>
<Site>...</Site>
<Site>...</Site>
</Category>
</Catalog>
```

**cat_3.php**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Catalog>
<Category>
<Name>Cat 3</Name>
<Site>...</Site>
<Site>...</Site>
<Site>...</Site>
</Category>
</Catalog>
```

Получаем XML файл

```
$url = 'https://site.ru/file.xml';


$fp = fopen("file.xml", "w");
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//var_dump($res);
$file = 'file.xml'; // файл XML

$read = simplexml_load_file($file); // получаем объект класса


$xml = $read->Category; // $xml - объект-массив, вложенные теги - его свойства;
$count = count($xml); // кол-во элементов массива
```

Название файлам брать из названия категории `<Name></Name>`, чтобы каждый раз конкретные файлы отвечали за конкретные категории.

Подскажите можно ли реализовать и как?

Спасибо!

Comment: Так, а зачем разделять? Я бы парсил XML и обновлял данные в БД с которой уже дальше работать и удобнее и быстрее.

Comment: Я не могу в базу сохранить данные более чем из одной категории https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927862/Как-перейти-к-следующему-объекту-после-прочтения-первого

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если с помощью регулярных выражений, то вот вам вариант:

```
$str = <<<STR
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Catalog>
<Category>
    <Name>Cat 1</Name>
    <Site>...</Site>
    <Site>...</Site>
    <Site>...</Site>
</Category>
<Category>
    <Name>Cat 2</Name>
    <Site>...</Site>
    <Site>...</Site>
    <Site>...</Site>
</Category>
<Category>
    <Name>Cat 3</Name>
    <Site>...</Site>
    <Site>...</Site>
    <Site>...</Site>
</Category>
</Catalog>
STR;

if (preg_match_all('~<Category>.+?</Category>~s', $str, $categories)) {
    foreach ($categories[0] as $category) {
        $temp = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . "\n<Catalog>\n$category\n</Catalog>\n";
        preg_match('~<Name>(.+?)</Name>~', $category, $filename);
        $filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $filename[1]) . '.php';
        $filename = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;
        file_exists($filename) ?: file_put_contents($filename, $temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MicroRu вот только почему у xml-файлов вы используете расширение `.php` я так и не понял.

Comment: Эдуард, большое спасибо! Про php по привычке написал, спасибо!

Comment: Просто шикарно!

Comment: Эдуард, а можно `$str = <<<STR ... STR;` заменить на url адрес XML файла лежащего на сервере или в интернете (без разницы)?

Comment: @MicroRu наверное нельзя, т.к. в переменной $str должен быть xml-код. Вам нужно модифицировать код из моего примера именно с учётом этого.

Comment: Хорошо, понял. Буду на лету придавать нужный вид.